# New comment buttons cut off comment text

Tags: bug, comments, action-buttons

New comment buttons cut off comment text. This appeared Friday August 17 2018.

[image: Buttons cutting off comment text]

Contrary to appearance of the image, I do not have custom CSS loaded. This is the standard High Constrast Black color settings. Color CSS is ignored and everything else is exactly the same. An image taken from standard settings would pixel-overlay this one.

Broswer: Firefox.

Comment: Somebody fixed it, no answer. I didn't change my Firefox version so that's not it.

Comment: Somebody broke it again.